# A problem in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ be its proper subgroup then $G =\bigcup gHg^{-1}$, where union varies over all $g$ belongs to $G$.

I thought like this :

It can be proved that if $G$ is a group then $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Hence $gHg^{-1}$ will give all possible subgroups of $G$. Hence, their union will give the whole group. Is my idea correct? If so, then, how can I prove it?... Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say “its proper subgroup” you imply that there is one and only one such proper subgroup; if you do not mean to imply that, then you shoudl say “**a** proper subbgroup”. Second, when you say “then”, do you mean to imply that $G$ will *necessarily* be the union of such conjugates? Because if that is the case, then you are wrong.

Comment: What if $H$ is a normal subgroup?...

Comment: “Therefore, $gHg^{-1}$ will give all possible subgroups”. What could make you believe such a thing? For starters, $gHg^{-1}$ will always have the same size as $H$, and usually, not every proper subgroup has the same size.

Comment: Moral: before spending time trying to prove a proposition, look at a few simple examples to see if it is true!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3):

It is not true that every finite group is the union of conjugates of a proper subgroup. For example, if $G$ is abelian, then $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$, and therefore the union will just be $H$, and never all of $G$ (since $H$ is given as a proper subgroup). For example, $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, $H=2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Even if $G$ is not abelian, the result may fail. For example, if $H$ is **normal**, then $gHg^{-1}=H$ for all $g\in G$, so the union is never all of $G$.  For example, $G=S_3$, $H=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$.

Even if $H$ is not normal, the result may fail. For example, take $G=S_4$, and $H=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$. Then every conjugate of $H$ lies in $A_4$, so $\cup_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\subseteq A_4\neq S_4=G$ (in fact, the union will be all of $A_4$).

In fact, as noted in comments, a finite group is *never* the union of conjugates of the same proper subgroup; though that is perhaps not immediately obvious. You can find a discussion of this and what happens when $G$ is infinite [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121526/union-of-the-conjugates-of-a-proper-subgroup).

Comment: Moreover, one can show that, if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is finite, the equality $G=\bigcup_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$ _never_ holds.