# Non-abelian finite group $G$ has at least 2 conjugacy classes which contain at least 2 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof

> Show that each non-abelian finite group $G$ has at least $2$ conjugacy classes which contain at least $2$ elements.

I have a solution which uses the class equation. However, as we have not dealt with this equation in class, we do not have it at our disposal.

> Is it possible to prove this proposition without the class equation?

My attempt looks like this:

As $G$ is non-abelian, there are $a$ and $b$ with $a\neq b$ such that $aba^{-1}\neq b $  and also $bab^{-1}\neq a $. Hence, in the conjugacy class of $b$, there are $b$ itself and $aba^{-1}$, which is why this class contains at least two distinct elements. The same can be done for the conjugacy class of $a$ which contains at least $a$ and $bab^{-1}$. At first glance, both classes seem to be distinct.

> However, could it be possible that both conjugacy classes are equal?

Then, this attempt of a proof would be invalid, of course.

Comment: Well, if $b=gag^{-1}$, then it is possible. For example take the transpositions $a=(12),\ b=(23)$ in $S_n$, $n\ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of your reasoning is correct.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that there is only one conjugacy class with more than $1$ element.  Then every non-central element is conjugate to every other non-central element.

In case all elements of $G$ are of order 2, then for any element $a,c\in G$ you will have $cac^{-1}=cac=caca\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}=a$.  So it is quite easy to analyze what will happen in this case.

Otherwise, pick an element $a\in G$ of order more than $2$.  Then there are $|G\setminus Z(G)|-o(a)+1$ elements to conjugate $a$ by (since conjugating $a$ by its powers or by things in the center will result in just $a$ again).  Therefore, there must be at least $o(a)-1+|Z(G)|$ elements that $a$ is *not* conjugate to.

Obviously, this would not be the case if $G$ were infinite.

Comment: I am not totally convinced of your argument: you say *Then every non-identity element is conjugate to every other non-identity element*, mustn't that be *Then every non-central element is conjugate to every other non-central element?* That is, $G-Z(G)$ is a single conjugacy class.

Comment: Yes -- when I wrote this I was thinking that each non-central element would form a conjugacy class of size more than one.  But other than that, the argument should go through regardless.

Answer (score 3):

To arrive at a contradiction assume for the moment that $G$ has only a *single* conjugacy class of cardinality greater than $1$. This implies that all non-central elements form a conjugacy class, say $G-Z(G)=Cl_G(x)$ for some $x \notin Z(G)$. Note, since $x\neq x^2$, $|C_G(x)| \geq 2$. This yields $|G:C_G(x)|=\#Cl_G(x) \leq |G|/2$, whence $|G|-|Z(G)| \leq |G|/2$, being equivalent to $|G|/2 \leq |Z(G)|$. But $G$ is not abelian, that is, $|Z(G)| \lt |G|$ and we conclude $|G|/2=|Z(G)|$ so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic (of order $2$), implying $G$ is abelian, a contradiction!

**Note** (added January 19th 2022) Here is a somewhat different and streamlined proof.

**Proposition** There do not exist finite groups $G$ having a *single* conjugacy class of cardinality $\gt 1$.
**Proof** Let $n \gt 1$ be the cardinality of the conjugacy class. Then by the Class Formula we have
$$|G|=|Z(G)|+n$$
Since $n$ is the index of some centralizer, by taking the equation mod $n$ we see that $|Z(G)| \equiv 0$ mod $n$, that is, $n \mid |Z(G)|$. Taking the equation mod $|Z(G)|$, we also see that $|Z(G)| \mid n$. We conclude that $|Z(G)|=n$ and $|G|=2n$. So, $|G/Z(G)| \cong C_2$ is cyclic and $G$ must be abelian, contradicting $n \gt 1$. $\square$

This line of reasoning also generalizes nicely to the non-existence of finite groups $G$ having *exactly 2* conjugacy classes of the *same* cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an element $a \in G$ that does not commute with $b \in G$. As you showed, this implies that the class $Cl_G(a)$ has cardinality at least $2$, or, equivalently, the index of the centralizer of $a$, $|G:C_G(a)| \geq 2$. This makes $C_G(a)$ a *proper* subgroup. Now use the fact that in a *finite* group, the union of all the conjugates of a proper subgroup cannot be the whole group (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121526/union-of-the-conjugates-of-a-proper-subgroup)). It follows that you can find an $x \in G$, with $x \notin \bigcup_{g \in G}C_G(a)^g=\bigcup_{g \in G}C_G(a^g)$. This implies that $a$ and $x$ do not commute and also that $Cl_G(a) \cap Cl_G(x) = \emptyset$.