# Prove that if $G$ is a finite group in which every proper subgroup is nilpotent, then $G$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

Prove that if $G$ is a finite group in which every proper subgroup is nilpotent, then $G$ is solvable. (Hint: Show that a minimal counterexample is simple. Let $M$ and $N$ be distinct maximal subgroups chose with $|M\cap N|$ as large as possible and apply Part 2 of Theorem 3. Now apply the methods of Exercise 53 in Section 4.5.)

This is Exercise 6.1.35 in Dummit and Foote. Using the idea from the hint, I tried the following proof. But I couldn't prove that $M\cap N=1$. Does anyone know how to prove this? Thanks.

Here is what I have done so far:

We proceed by induction. If $|G|=2$, then $G$ is clearly solvable. Let $|G|\geq6$. Assume that the statement is true for all groups of order $<|G|$.

If $G$ is of prime order, then clearly $G$ is solvable. So we assume that $G$ is not of prime order. Since $G$ is finite, $G$ contains nontrivial maximal subgroups.

Claim: There exists a maximal subgroup of $G$ which is normal. Suppose not. Since conjugates of a maximal subgroup are maximal subgroups, $G$ has more than one maximal subgroups. Let $M$ and $N$ be the distinct maximal subgroups such that $|M\cap N|$ is maximal. Since $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent, $M\cap N<N_M(M\cap N)$ and $M\cap N<N_N(M\cap N)$. (Here I want to show that $M\cap N=1$ following the hint.)

Now since $G\neq\bigcup_{g\in G}gMg^{-1}$, there exists $H\leq G$ maximal such that $H$ is not a conjugate of $M$. So $G$ has at least the following number of nonidentity elements:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(|M|-1)|G:N_G(M)|+(|H|-1)|G:N_G(H)|=&(|M|-1)|G:M|+(|H|-1)|G:H|\\=&2|G|-|G:M|-|G:H|\\\geq&2|G|-\frac{1}{2}|G|-\frac{1}{2}|G|=|G|
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which is a contradiction. Hence there exists a maximal subgroup of $G$ which is normal.

Now let $M\unlhd G$ be a maximal subgroup. Then $M$ is nilpotent and hence solvable. Now $|G/M|<|G|$. Since every subgroup of $G$ is nilpotent, by the correspondence theorem, every subgroup of $G/M$ is nilpotent. So $G/M$ is solvable. Hence $G$ is solvable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is not complete and also incorrect. Here is a proof. If $G$ is not solvable, then one of the composition factors $B/A$ is simple non-Abelian. If $B$ is a proper subgroup then $B$ is nilpotent, hence $B/A$ is nilpotent, a contradiction. So $B=G$. Similarly if $A\ne 1$, then $|G/A|<|G|$, all proper subgroups of $G/A$ are nilpotent, hence $G/A$ is solvable.Since $A$ is nilpotent, $G$ is solvable.

Thus $G=G/A=B/A$ is simple non-Abelian.

The shortest way to finish is then by using J. Thompson's famous theorem about classification of all simple finite groups where [all proper subgroups are solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-group_(finite_group_theory)#:%7E:text=More%20generally%20Thompson%20showed%20that,groups%20U3(q).). Each of these groups contains non-nilpotent solvable subgroups. QED

Now a longer way suggested by D-F. $G$ contains at least two maximal subgroups $M,K$ since $G$ is simple. Assume that $L=M\cap K$ is maximal possible. Since $M,K$ are nilpotent $N_1=N_M(L)>L<N_2=N_K(L)$ (Theorem 3 in D-F). If $L$ is not 1, its normalizer in $G$ is not $G$ (again because $G$ is simple), whence that normalizer must be inside some maximal subgroup $K'$ of $G$. But then $K'\ge N_1$, hence $K'\cap M$ is bigger than $L$, a contradiction. Thus $L=1$ and the intersection of any two maximal subgroups of $G$ is trivial.

We can assume that $M$ and $K$ are not conjugate. Note that $N_G(M)=M, N_G(K)=K$ since these subgroups are maximal and not normal. Hence there are $[G:M]$ conjugates of $M$ each two intersecting trivially and there are $[G:K]$ conjugates of $K$ each two intersecting trivially. Altogether these subgroups contain $2|G|-[G:K]-[G:M]+1$ elements. Note that the indices of these maximal subgroups are not bigger than $|G|/2$ by Lagrange's theorem. So  $2|G|-[G:K]-[G:M]+1\ge |G|+1$ a contradiction.

Comment: Since this is an exercise in a book, you are presumably not supposed to cite results from outside of the book when solving it. It is possible to solve it just by following the hints given.

Comment: The maximal subgroups cannot have order $|G|/2$ because then they would be normal. This shortens things a little.

Comment: True. You want that $|M|=2$, not $|G:M|=2$. Another contradiction is that $M$ and $K$ are now non-conjugate Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$, of course.

Comment: @JCAA Thanks very much!!! I want wondering how to use the first sentence in the hint "Show that a minimal counterexample is simple." Now it makes sense.

Comment: Why can we assume $M$ and $K$ are not conjugate?

Comment: @MateusFigueiredo See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121526)

Comment: Thank you, Derek.